# Javascript Determine 10 days before specific date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime

So I am currently fetching some records from my database, and one of the records is a 'last edited' which is a date. However, I just want to display this 10 days before it has been exactly one year since the specific date. How would I approach this? I know how to deal with arrays and the fetching itself, but I'm not sure how I would deal with the date?

This is what I've done so far:

```
var startDate = fetchedDate;
var validDate = new Date(startDate);
var fullYear = validDate.getFullYear();
validDate.setFullYear(fullYear + 1);
```

And then I need to create a new date to compare it, I suppose? But how? I also want to know how many days it is until it has been one year.

Comment: use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) for dates, makes it easy

Comment: wich database? a [mcve] please

Comment: @JonasW. I use Firebase. But that's not really my concern, what I'm wondering is how I would use 'if else' - in my criteria.

Comment: @baao I'll check it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna make it with pure javascript you can

```
var startDate = fetchedDate;
var validDate = new Date(startDate);
validDate.setYear(validDate.getFullYear() - 1);
validDate.setDate(validDate.getDate() - 10);
```

But I also will recommend you to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), is a very good javascript library to handle dates, otherwise sometimes is like trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: should be validDate in line 3 instead of myDate

Comment: You're right, thanks!!

Comment: Also, getYear is deprecated, use getFullYear

Comment: I would strongly advise to rely on momentjs only, as manipulating dates is always tricky because of all the edge cases. You can find many articles on the subject (google "date manipulation edge cases").